# How to catch uncaught exception from QThread in python

Tags: python, exception, pyqt, qthread

Is it possible in `Python` to catch `uncaught exceptions` thrown in a `QThread`, so that the parent thread catch exceptions from the children thread.
In Java I would have used an UncaughtExceptionHandler for this.